# Can't get a linter to work in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, linter

I recently decided to try out atom, but noticed that there was no linter built in (at least for js, which is what I am using it for). So I downloaded linter (2.2.0), and linter-eslint (8.4.1), restarted atom, saved my code, and still, nothing happened. Why can't I get it to work?